# Userdefined function for printf

Tags: c++, c, model-view-controller, visual-c++

Is it possible to replace printf with userdefined function or is it possible to create function similar like printf

Comment: The answer depends on what you need this for.

Comment: Its an interview question
Want to write a function which do the same what printf is doing

Comment: Look into creating your own output stream.

Comment: What do you exactly wish to achieve? Can't the same thing be done using printf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can define [variadic functions](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=138) (the technical name for functions with a variable number of arguments, like `printf`) -- the URL I've pointed to is one reference for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Go look at the source for [printf](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=printf+c+source+code&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), or [_VFPRINTF_R](http://code.google.com/p/mosync/source/browse/MoSync/trunk/libs/newlib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c?r=812&spec=svn812) in this case, and see if that is something you want to write.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own version of printf, you can do something like this once it is defined

```
/*
 * Make printfs use your new printf
 */
#define printf my_printf
```

and define your `my_printf` however you like

As for how printf could be written, have a look at The C Programming Language by K&R. It has a section on how `printf` function might be written.